# profiling dynamic library in linux using perf

Tags: linux, c++11, cmake, shared-libraries, perf

I have decision tree classifer class implemented in C++ and I want to profile only C++ shared library of my decision tree class. I am using linux perf tool but I do not want to profile the whole application just the shared library which I have created for decision tree class.

is it possible to generate perf.data for shared library and then get a flame graph?

any help will be highly appreciated in this regards,

Arslan

Comment: It is possible to profile your application in full  with `perf record ./application` and then focus on shared library dso in interactive `perf report` (find any sample from the library, open menu and select focus on library.so; or `perf report -d library.so`). You can also filter samples decoded from perf.data file like `perf script | grep library.so | less`.

Comment: sounds great. let me try this. many thanks